# Add and parse my own JSON object in my Shopify Liquid theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, shopify, liquid

I added a JSON file to the assets folder in my Shopify liquid theme. I want to get and parse this JSON object in a jquery method from a javascript file in my assets folder. I've tried including the json file as an asset_url and I've tried using jquery's getJSON() method with the asset's path but the file can't be found. Does anyone know a good approach for adding a custom data object to a shopify liquid theme and the best way to access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save your JSON in a .liquid file and include it in your template. You'd define the JSON like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.my_json_obj = {
           ...
           }
</script>
```

That way, you could access `window.my_json_obj` in your jQuery script. But if a key/value storage approach is enough for your needs, you should probably take a look at Shopify's [metafields](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/metafield)

Comment: much obliged @TatianaFrank :)